# A logical way to back trace the corresponding regex from an OR (|) operation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

While running a preg_match with OR (|), is there a logical way to determine the matching regex.

```
@regex = ~^(?|/|/about|/about/class/(?<id>[^/]+)/fox|/about/class/(?<id>[^/]+)/(?<type>[^/]+)/fox|/about/class/(?<id>[^/]+)/(?<type>[^/]+)/fox/(?<boat>[^/]+))$~x

preg_match(@regex, '/about/class/test1/test2/fox', $results);
```

The example will match & provide me the named groups as needed

```
matches /about/class/(?<id>[^/]+)/(?<type>[^/]+)/fox in @regex
id = test1
type = test2
```

is there a logical way to find what part of @regex matched?

FOUND A SOLUTION:

```
|/about/class/([^/]+)/fox(*MARK:some-name)|...
```

the results array will then contain a MARK key containing the 'some-name'. Idea here is to have a separate data structure that maps 'some-name' to corresponding regex. This allows easy use of branch reset "?|"

Comment: That also doesn't look exactly like PHP, are you using some framework? By `to find what part of @regex` do you mean at what position a match occurred, or what percentage of the string was matched, or something else?

Comment: it is php (regex syntax)...i just wrote in pseudo-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may define a group-pattern array first, use a non-capturing group instead of a branch reset, wrap each alternative with a named group following the group-pattern array and name each sub-group with a group name as suffix.

Then you may use

```
$groupmap = ['one' => '/', 'two' => '/about', 'three' => '/about/class/(?<id>[^/]+)/fox',
             'five' => '/about/class/(?<id>[^/]+)/(?<type>[^/]+)/fox/(?<boat>[^/]+)'];
$regex = '~^(?:(?<one>/)|(?<two>/about)|(?<three>/about/class/(?<idthree>[^/]+)/fox)|(?<four>/about/class/(?<idfour>[^/]+)/(?<typefour>[^/]+)/fox)|(?<five>/about/class/(?<idfive>[^/]+)/(?<typefive>[^/]+)/fox/(?<boatfive>[^/]+)))$~x';
if (preg_match($regex, '/about/class/test1/test2/fox/someboat', $m)) {
    foreach ($groupmap as $name => $pattern ) {
       if (isset($m[$name]) && !empty($m[$name])) {
           echo "Group '" . $name . "' matched: " . $pattern . "\n";
           echo "ID: " . (!empty($m["id".$name]) ? $m["id".$name] : "None") . "\n";
           echo "TYPE: " . (!empty($m["type".$name]) ? $m["type".$name] : "None") . "\n";
           echo "BOAT: " . (!empty($m["boat".$name]) ? $m["boat".$name] : "None");
       }
    }
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/umg4t)

Output:

```
Group 'five' matched: /about/class/(?<id>[^/]+)/(?<type>[^/]+)/fox/(?<boat>[^/]+)
ID: test1
TYPE: test2
BOAT: someboat
```